# a contradictory result when checking an example of "Linking with external libraries"

Tags: c, gcc

I just started to learn gcc/g++ by reading "[An introduction to GCC](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/)"

In chapter 3.1 the author showed an example of linking with external libraries and header files. The main source code uses 'gdbm.h' header (installed at /opt/gdbm-1.8.3/include/ in text book) file and the library ‘libgdbm.a’ (installed at /opt/gdbm-1.8.3/lib/ in text book). The process of linking with the library and header file is as follows:

[Link to example screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg2gnv3e79ht9fx/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202015-06-20%20%E4%B8%8A%E5%8D%889.58.15.png?dl=0)

When I tried to repeat this, I got a contradictory result. When I used method 1 (in the example fails) which only includes header file path, the program can be compiled, however, when I used method 2 (in the example succeeds), I got an error, saying that 
"ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

(this is my full command line and error message:)

```
userMacBook-Pro:03 user$gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include dbmain.c -L/usr/local/lib dbmain.c -lgdbm
duplicate symbol _main in:
/var/folders/6_/09vfzzms7dq1d73vl4mwlxmh0000gn/T/dbmain-9d15f9.o
/var/folders/6_/09vfzzms7dq1d73vl4mwlxmh0000gn/T/dbmain-907e96.o
```

this is my command that succeeds:

```
userMacBook-Pro:03 user$ gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include dbmain.c -lgdbm
userMacBook-Pro:03 user$ ./a.out
Storing key-value pair... done.
```

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone explain why this happens?

I don't know which platform the author uses, I just use mac OS X.

Comment: You need to show your full command line and error message.  (In particular, it is important to know which symbol is the duplicate.)

Comment: Hi @EwanMellor I added my full command line and error message. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include dbmain.c -L/usr/local/lib dbmain.c -lgdbm`

The file `dbmain.c` is present twice on your command line. For this reason the `main` function is present twice.

Comment: Ummm.... That is my fault... Thanks. However, I can still compile successfully by using method 1 which fails in the textbook

Comment: Your method 1 succeeds because you have libgdbm installed in a path that gcc is searching by default.  The book is using a path inside /opt, which gcc will not search by default, so you need the `-L` option.  If the library is inside /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib then gcc will find it without the `-L` option because it knows to search those places.